# Caffe-segnt Compilation Error

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I am facing this error while compiling caffe-segnet.
here is my terminal when i used
 ~/.local/install/caffe-segnet$ make all

```
CXX src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp
src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void caffe::ContrastiveLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&, const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&) [with Dtype = float]’:
src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp:118:1:   required from here
src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp:56:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘max(double, float)’
         Dtype dist = std::max(margin - sqrt(dist_sq_.cpu_data()[i]), Dtype(0.0));
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61:0,
                 from src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:219:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:219:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp:56:30: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const _Tp’ (‘double’ and ‘float’)
         Dtype dist = std::max(margin - sqrt(dist_sq_.cpu_data()[i]), Dtype(0.0));
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61:0,
                 from src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:265:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Compare> const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare)
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:265:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp:56:30: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const _Tp’ (‘double’ and ‘float’)
         Dtype dist = std::max(margin - sqrt(dist_sq_.cpu_data()[i]), Dtype(0.0));
                              ^
Makefile:526: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.o] Error 1
```

Comment: this ERROR is solved by Replacing Line no 56 of  contrastive_loss_layer.cpp file with this

Dtype dist = std::max(margin - (float)sqrt(dist_sq_.cpu_data()[i]), Dtype(0.0));     and  make all done successfully but a new  ERROR raised while make runtest      
Makefile:526: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_power_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_power_layer.o] Error 1